# string type alias is not assignable to string in Recoil with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recoiljs

```js
export type OrderOption =
  | '-createdAt'
  | 'participationFee';

export const orderState = atom<OrderOption>({
  key: 'order',
  default: '-createdAt',
});

interface OrderListProps {
  options: { name: string; content: string }[];
  recoilState: RecoilState<string>;
}

const OrderList = ({ options, recoilState }: OrderListProps) => {
return some components }
```

and When I try rendering

```js
<OrderList options={ORDER_OPTIONS} recoilState={orderState} />
```

It causes ts(2322) error that says `RecoilState<OrderOption>` isn't assignable to `RecoilState<string>`.

If vice versa I understand the error, but `OrderOption` is still string overall so I don't understand why it's problematic. How can I solve this?

Comment: What is `RecoilState`?

Comment: It's similar to state in `useState` but used in Recoil. its composition is like this (sorry it's long) `export class RecoilState<T> extends AbstractRecoilValue<T> {}
 ` `declare class AbstractRecoilValue<T> {
  __tag: [T];
  __cTag: (t: T) => void; // for contravariance

  key: NodeKey;
  constructor(newKey: NodeKey);
  toJSON(): {key: string};
 }`

Comment: The type `RecoilState` contains a function where the argument is of type `T`. Therefore it is contravariant. This answer should clear things up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covariance-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc

Answer (score 1):

`RecoilState<'order' | '-createdAt'>` is **not** the same as `RecoilState<string>`.

---

Define `recoilState` as `RecoilState<'order' | '-createdAt'>`

*(Same as `RecoilState<OrderOption>)`*

Comment: well I know I can define `recoilState` like that but I wanted to use `string` because I think I might need to add more string type aliases in the future due to lots kinds of order options :( Why is `RecoilState<'order' | '-createdAt'>` not the same as `RecoilState<string>` ?

Comment: Please provide your full code with the definition of `RecoilState` and the definition of `OrderList` (with the expected input variable types). And what does `atom()` exactly do? Why `key` and `default`? If you provide these informations, I can explain your scenario better and I will edit my answer.